# Is there a way to loop/repeat DVD on the ps2?

Tags: ps2

Is there a repeat function for DVDs on the Playstation 2? I would like a DVD to loop until manually stopped.

Comment: have you looked at all the commands it can do yourself?

Comment: Problem is that I don't have the console here. Im just making a DVD for my spouse to loop through

Comment: oh alright, just throwing that out there. A lot of people solve their own problems on here after looking harder is all lol

Answer (score 2):

[image: PS2 DVD remote controller]

If you have the remote controller for the PS2, there is a button specifically for that (`REPEAT`). I'm not sure if it is possible without the remote unfortunately. Maybe someone else can give a better answer.

Comment: You can find it under 10$ at Ebay, but... yeah it's a bit expensive for a loop function.

Comment: I know there is a repeat function for the CD playback. So might by for just that.